# Override woocommerce class files

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to make some modifications to a function in WooCommerce, on a file called class-wc-frontend-scripts.php in woocommerce/includes/

The function I'm looking to modify is:

```php
private static function get_script_data( $handle ) {
    global $wp;

    switch ( $handle ) {
        case 'wc-single-product' :
            return array(
                'i18n_required_rating_text' => esc_attr__( 'Please select a rating', 'woocommerce' ),
                'review_rating_required'    => get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_required' ),
                'flexslider'                => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', array(
                    'rtl'            => is_rtl(),
                    'animation'      => 'slide',
                    'smoothHeight'   => true,
                    'directionNav'   => false,
                    'controlNav'     => 'thumbnails',
                    'slideshow'      => false,
                    'animationSpeed' => 500,
                    'animationLoop'  => false, // Breaks photoswipe pagination if true.
                ) ),
                'zoom_enabled'       => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' ) ),
                'photoswipe_enabled' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' ) ),
                'photoswipe_options' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_options', array(
                    'shareEl'               => false,
                    'closeOnScroll'         => false,
                    'history'               => false,
                    'hideAnimationDuration' => 0,
                    'showAnimationDuration' => 0
                ) ),
                'flexslider_enabled' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' ) ),
            );
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For my product slider, I need to show prev and next arrows on single product page. So I need to change 'directionNav' as true.

How do I do this without making changes to the core files?

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a child theme yet? If not, that's your first step. Here's a link from the WordPress codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Then instead of editing that core file, you hook into that function instead, and write that code inside of the functions.php file you created in your child theme. If you want to add code to the existing function, you'll want to use an action hook. If you want to modify the code, you use a filter. It looks like you're trying to change the code, so probably a filter is best.

Here's how it would look using a filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_script_data', 'change_nav_direction' );

 function change_nav_direction( $variable ) {
   //any other code you may need

                'directionNav'   => true,

 //you must have a return
 return $variable;
}
```

Here's a link to an article from WooCommerce that might help:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Already I have created child theme. However here I would like to confirm that I have to return the same array with changed values or to return the changed values only

Comment: Hey sorry, I just realized my last comment was not helpful at all. So it looks like WooCommerce is creating its own filter that hooks into `woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options`, so I think you'd actually want to hook into that function. And then you should just have to change the one value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the filter for woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options. Works for me.